# Does not have to element of Schwartz space vanish on the boundary?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

[image]

This is Fourier transform of element of Schwartz space in $\mathbb{R}^n$ from the book  but in the explanation on the boundary $f$ vanishes. As much as i know the element of Schwartz space does not have to vanish . Is it true or wrong? Or Why is it explained in this way ? Thank you .

Comment: Integration by parts : $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'(x) e^{-i \omega x}dx = f(x)e^{-i \omega x}|_{-\infty}^\infty + \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) i \omega e^{-i \omega x}dx$$ And since $f$ is Schwartz $f(x)e^{-i \omega x}|_{-\infty}^\infty = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vague idea is that the "boundary" is at infinity, where the Schwartz functions do vanish. What's really going on is that we write the integral over $\mathbb R^n$ as the limit of the integral over $B_R(0)$ as $R \to \infty$, then do the integration by parts over the ball. The boundary terms are thus integrals over the sphere $\partial B_R$, which has measure proportional to $R^{n-1}$; so since Schwartz functions shrink faster than any polynomial in $R$, these integrals vanish in the limit $R \to \infty$.